# Else and If not working properly Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
<body style="text-align:center;">
        <form>
        <label id="agefield" for="age">age:</label><input id="age" type="text" maxlength="2" />
        <button id="subButton" class="button" >Enter</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script>
            function age() {
                var age= document.getElementById('age').value;
                var result= document.getElementById('result');

                if (age>=18) {
                    result.textContent = 'You Must be 18 and above to enter';
                }
                else {
                    result.textContent = 'Welcome click <a href=#> here </a> to enter xguineapig';
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            var el = document.getElementById('subButton');
                el.addEventListener('click', age, false);
            });
        </script> 
    </body>
```

Comment: Please explain what's wrong.

Comment: Your condition is wrong. `>=` means `greater than or equal to`. What you want is `<=` less than or equal to

Comment: @Rajesh  You mean you want `<` not `<=`  :)

Comment: actually, you want < 18, or swap the text between if and else blocks

Comment: Only `<` and not `<=`. I already answered below. Anyway next time provide more detail in question!!

Comment: Also FWIW your missing your closing form tag..

Comment: I don't see where you close the `</form>` tag

Comment: @Keith Yup. You are right

Comment: Whoever upvoted this question should be taken out and shot.

Comment: @Dsenese1  you could just put it before the script tag, or alternatively just remove the form tag as it's not required anyway..

Comment: Holy shit, novices don't know how to ask questions! Let's bully them out of our site, that will teach them.

Comment: @Maia, holy shit, some novices do not make any effort at reading our extensive documentation before asking, nor do they have the common sense of at least *asking* something! Let's upvote their questions so we get more of them.

Comment: Yes let's upvote it, that is totally the solution, screw the idea of just sending a honest, friendly message explaining what he did wrong, how to do it right, and locking the thread, that is for barbarians.

Answer (score 4):

You have to check if is `<18` if you want to show that message, not `>=`.

Else, use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` to display correctly the `<a>`.

And, more, as commented out by others, close your `form` tag.

PS: next time provide more detail in your question, people shouldn't try to guess what you're asking for.

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <form>
    <label id="agefield" for="age">age:</label>
    <input id="age" type="text" maxlength="2" />
    <button id="subButton" class="button">Enter</button>
  </form>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <script>
      function age() {
        var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result');

        if (age < 18) {
          result.innerHTML = 'You Must be 18 and above to enter';
        } else {
          result.innerHTML = 'Welcome click <a href=#> here </a> to enter xguineapig';
        }
      }
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var el = document.getElementById('subButton');
        el.addEventListener('click', age, false);
      });
  </script>
</body>
```